# I can't connect to a remote db using java in netbeans and apache server

Tags: java, sql, apache, netbeans

I am trying to connect to my apache server remotly. I manged to allow my db and server to be accessed with my ip but when i try to test the connection to my db using the integrated netbeans connection tool i can only reach it using my localhost

I have tried to set the bind address in apache but that breaks my server and i need to reinstall it every time. I have also added full privilages to my user and can access it using a separate ip.

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my ip)
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

```
("jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/dbname", "root", "password");
```

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The error log:

```
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1797710
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1797719; transaction id 225
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190703 18:55:56
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'.
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context.


2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-07-03 18:55:56 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

- First you need to create a user with all privilages that can connect to any host aka root@%.
- Then you need to open port 3306 on your router and send all the traffic to your machine that has the server.
- Aside from that password is mandatory, to be secure

Answer (score 0):

You allowed remote access for your Apache server but not for the MySQL server. To allow remote access for MySQL you need to modify the `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address    = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

For a detailed instruction see for example here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: When i try to add my public ip the server wont start at all. I have also granted all the permissions to said user

Comment: If the MySQL server is not coming up, show us the log-file.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/errorlog This comes up when i use my public ip when i use my machines (192.168.x.x) works as intended